# Why is ScrollOwner not set?

Tags: c#, wpf

I develop test driven and want to test, that my control which implements `IScrollInfo` returns the correct ScrollViewer. Additionally I'd like to test that my control called `InvalidateScrollInfo` on the ScrollOwner.

The control looks like:

```
private class MyControl : UserControl, IScrollInfo
{
    public ScrollViewer ScrollOwner { get; set; }

    ... other code to implement IScrollInfo
}
```

My test (nunit) looks like:

```
[Test]
public void Should_be_scrollable()
{
    var ControlToTest = new MyControl();
    var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer { Content = ControlToTest };
    var window = new Window { Content = scrollViewer };
    window.Show();

    Assert.That(ControlToTest, Is.InstanceOf<IScrollInfo>());
    Assert.That(ControlToTest.ScrollOwner, Is.SameAs(scrollViewer));
}
```

But unfortunately the `Assert.That(ControlToTest.ScrollOwner, Is.SameAs(scrollViewer));` fails because the `ScrollOwner` is `null`.

**Question** Why is `ControlToTest.ScrollOwner` null?

**What I did**: I looked where the ScrollOwner gets set. This happens in the `HookupScrollingComponents` in the `ScrollContentPresenter`, which in turn is called in `OnApplyTemplate`. And for my understanding the template is applied when the element gets measured. And this should be done when the window is shown. Even when I added `window.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);` to form:

```
[Test]
public void Should_be_scrollable()
{
    var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer { Content = ControlToTest };
    var window = new Window { Content = scrollViewer };
    window.Show();
    window.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);

    Assert.That(ControlToTest, Is.InstanceOf<IScrollInfo>());
    Assert.That(ControlToTest.ScrollOwner, Is.SameAs(scrollViewer));
}
```

it didn't help. The `ScrollOwner` is still `null`. Why?

**Bonus question**: How do I test that `InvalidateScrollInfo()` was called on the `scrollViewer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neccessary, that the `CanContentScroll` is set to `true`.

Than the test works:

```
[Test]
public void Should_be_scrollable()
{
    var ControlToTest = new MyControl();
    var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer
    {
        Content = ControlToTest,
        CanContentScroll = true
    };
    var window = new Window { Content = scrollViewer };
    window.Show();

    Assert.That(ControlToTest, Is.InstanceOf<IScrollInfo>());
    Assert.That(ControlToTest.ScrollOwner, Is.SameAs(scrollViewer));
}
```

Now further tests with the `ControlToTest.ScrollOwner` can be performed.

Answer to Bonus question: when you change the `ControlToTest.ViewportHeight` to be smaller than the `ControlToTest.ExtentHeight` in the test, then you can check the `ControlToTest.ScrollOwner.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to assert that the `ScrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo()` was called. This might look like:

```
var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer
{
    Content = ControlToTest,
    CanContentScroll = true,
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
};
var window = new Window { Content = scrollViewer, Height = 600 };
window.Show();
Assert.That(
    ControlToTest.ScrollOwner.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility,
    Is.EqualTo(Visibility.Collapsed));

window.Height = 300;
Render();

Assert.That(
    ControlToTest.ScrollOwner.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility,
    Is.EqualTo(Visibility.Visible));
```

with

```
private void Render()
{
    ControlToTest.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing the UI is tricky, what happens in WPF is, Actions get Queued onto the Dispatcher, and only executed once the UI thread is free. So a lot of the initialization after window.Show() won't happen until you release the thread for the UI to do its bindings/initialization, and schedule a task onto the dispatcher with a really low priority that will do the assertion. This can be very tricky in a Unit Test.